# Unusual equation(s) obtained at an attempt to solve an open problem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, nonlinear-system

While trying to solve an open problem I arrived at the following equation:

$$56l^3+60l^2+10l+6=6\sum_{j=1}^{l+1}a_jb_j$$ , where $a_j,b_j$ are constrained by $1<a_j,b_j<4l$, for $j=1,...,l+1$

$a_j,b_j$ can be more precisely constrained but I will not go now into details because even this looks complicated enough.

Now, further constraints: $a_j$ and $b_j$ are also all odd and we have $a_j \neq b_j$ and we have that all $a_ib_i$ are different and we also must have $  4 | a_jb_j - a_ib_i$ and we must also have this extremely strong divisibility condition $ (i-j) | a_ib_i-a_jb_j$.

Here we, in fact, have an infinite number of equations, because we get for every natural $l \in \mathbb N$ one non-linear Diophantine equation.

Honestly, I do not know who to consult when it comes to this problem.

What to do?

Comment: There is nothing to do so far.  You have an equation.  Is there something the equation is supposed to tell you?  What problem are you working on?

Comment: @abiessu Do you want to chat about this?

Comment: Previously asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/289549/12357

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Now deleted on MO.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the equation for $l-1$ from the equation for $l$ and divide by 6 to get $a_{l+1}b_{l+1}=28l^2-8l+1<(4l)^2=16l^2$, so $12l^2-8l+1=(2l-1)(6l-1)<0$, i.e. $1/6<l<1/2$. But since $l$ is an integer, the problem has no solutions.

*Update:* Apparently, now $a_i$’s and $b_i$’s may be different for different $l$, so this answer has been rendered obsolete.

Comment: This only means that no solution for $l$ can be obtained by extending a solution for $l-1$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I also have the condition $a_i \neq b_i$, but I do not know is that relevant, but as I see your solutions, it might be, should I add that to the post also?

Comment: I will add that since it could be very important to the structure of solutions.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen How possibly can I know an answer to this? Relevant for what??

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Oops sorry I did not notice the condition that they all must be odd!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, they must. Thank you for your attention and help. You can, if you want to, write an answer that contains "all the help" someone can get in dealing with problems of this kind.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen I don't think what I have so far is enough for an answer. There seem to be no solutions for $l=2$ or $l=3$. As for $l=4$ there are lots of solutions, e. g. $a=(5,11,13,13,13)$, $b=(3,15,15,15,15)$ or, say, $a=(5,11,13,13,15)$, $b=(3,15,15,15,13)$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I did some more computations, we also must have $ 4 | a_jb_j - a_ib_i$ Does that narrow the space of solutions much?

Comment: It must narrow it pretty much.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე At the time I was posting the answer, the question seemed to imply that the same $a_j$’s and $b_j$’s should satisfy the sum condition for every $l$. I checked the statement carefully several times to make sure that’s what it meant. Now, of course, things seem to have changed.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Yes there have been several crucially altering edits afterwards. Maybe it is better to wait for the thing to stabilize :D

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether the following description suffices for your purposes.

Let $n=\frac{56l^3+60l^2+10l+6}6$; note that $n$ is an integer.

Take any decomposition $n=m_1+...+m_{l+1}$ of $n$ into a sum of $l+1$ numbers which satisfy $m_i<16l^2$, $m_i\equiv m_j\mod4$, are all odd but neither primes nor squares of primes.

Choose any proper divisors $a_i|m_i$, $i=1,...,l+1$ with $a_i^2\ne m_i$, $m_i/4l<a_i<4l$. Then $(a_1,...,a_{l+1})$, $(b_1,...,b_{l+1})=(\frac{m_1}{a_1},...,\frac{m_{l+1}}{a_{l+1}})$ is a solution, and every solution can be obtained in this way.

There are no solutions for $l=2,3$; for $l=4$ there are, up to reorderings, 5 solutions:

```
(7,11,11,11,11),(15,15,15,15,15)
(7,11,11,11,15),(15,15,15,15,11)
(7,11,11,15,15),(15,15,15,11,11)
(7,11,15,15,15),(15,15,11,11,11)
(7,15,15,15,15),(15,11,11,11,11)
```

**Update:** with the last divisibility condition, there seem to be no solutions for $l=5,6,7,8$

Comment: I am probably annoying with all these things I manage to find, but now I also discovered that the solutions must obey $a_{i+2}b_{i+2}-a_ib_i \neq 0$. I am constantly doing more and more research into what are all the important conditions and finding new ones constantly. Of course, there is not a myriad of them.

Comment: It might well be that already without decomposing into $a_ib_i$, just the additive problem of finding decompositions $n=m_1+...+m_{l+1}$ (with $n$ as in the answer) with all of your restrictions (they all can be formulated in terms of the $m_i$ alone) together with $1<m_i\leqslant(4l-1)^2$ odd, not prime, and not a square of a prime, may have no solutions at all. At any rate, given description of all solutions for this one it is then straightforward to describe all solutions with $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: With your condition $a_{i+2}b_{i+2}\ne a_ib_i$, do you assume $a_1b_1\leqslant a_2b_2\leqslant\cdots\leqslant a_{l+1}b_{l+1}$? Because in the question no ordering is mentioned.

Comment: That is also true, and true with $\leq$ swapped to $<$

Comment: You mean one can assume all $a_ib_i$ different?

Comment: Right, they are indeed.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Please add this condition in the question, it is very essential

Comment: Added right now.

Comment: Are there any solutions for any $l$ with that condition?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen So far I found no solutions at all and I think I slowly head towards a proof that there are none. The rough idea is this: bring to a contradiction that $m_{l+1}\leqslant(4l-1)^2$, that $m_{l+1}=m_1+k_1l=m_2+k_2(l-1)=...$, that $m_i=m_1+4k_i'l$ (each $k$ nonzero and  $0<k'_1<k'_2<\cdots$) and that each $m_i$ is odd, neither prime, nor square of a prime. Experimentally already these conditions seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: If you succeed in finding a proof then we can talk about all of this by e-mail, if you want.

Comment: There should be no solutions for all $l$

Comment: OK yes I will post it here if it works out.

Comment: Not only for this but for far more general problems, similar to this one, there should be no solutions.

Comment: Again experimentally, if one looks at all possible such $l+1$-tuples, the maximal possible sums are as follows: for $l=3$, $244$ with $n=348$; for $l=4$, $607$ with $n=765$; for $l=5$, $1114$ and $n=1426$; for $l=6$, $2017$ and $n=2387$, ... so that the difference between possble maximum and needed $n$ seems to grow

Comment: If that is true in general that would even strengthen this conjecture of mine. That is, if that does not follow almost trivially from the conditions.

Comment: You can right now give me here, if it is safe, your e-mail, so that I have it, There we can talk more about all of this.

Comment: You can now delete your comment if you wish, I will send you an e-mail message.